# Alternative of Java String.split for better performance

Tags: java, arrays, performance, api, split

In the process of adding data by import from a csv/tab seperated file, my code consumes a lot of time to upload data. Is there any alternative to do this in a more faster way ?? This is the code i use to split fields in an array.

```
 //Here -  lineString = fileReader.readLine()

public static String [] splitAndGetFieldNames(String lineString ,String fileType) 
{
    if(lineString==null || lineString.trim().equals("")){
        return null;
    }
    System.out.print("LINEEEE   " +  lineString);
    String pattern = "(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))";
    if(fileType.equals("tab"))
        pattern = "\t" + pattern;
    else
        pattern = "," + pattern;

    String fieldNames[] = lineString.split(pattern);


    for(int i=0 ; i < fieldNames.length ; i++){
        //logger.info("Split Fields::"+fieldNames[i]);
        if (fieldNames[i].startsWith("\""))
            fieldNames[i] = fieldNames[i].substring(1);
        if (fieldNames[i].endsWith("\""))
            fieldNames[i] = fieldNames[i].substring(0, fieldNames[i].length()-1);
        fieldNames[i] = fieldNames[i].replaceAll("\"\"","\"").trim();
        //logger.info("Split Fields after manipulation::"+fieldNames[i]);
    }
    return fieldNames;
}
```

Comment: Did you try using a CSV parser instead of reinventing the wheel? It may be optimized and faster than your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CSV parser like [super-csv](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html).

Univocity provides a [benchmark of CSV parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison). It says that [univocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/)
 is fast, which is no surprise. You could give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to take a look at [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) library or try [CSVParser](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html) from `Apache Commons`

Anyway, reinventing the wheel is not the best idea. Using 3rd party library would be less headache than writing it yourself :)