# How do I validate text file contents in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, validation

I'm creating a program which reads the contents of a .txt file, it validates and then outputs the contents of that file in a nice formatted table. My program currently reads the file and then outputs the content, I'm trying to implement the validation of said file content.

I'll now explain the way my program reads the file:

The .txt contents:

```
firstname lastname
Gameone : 120 : 1428 
Gametwo : 20 : 10 
Gamethree : 90 : 800 
Gamefour : 190 : 2001 
Gamefive : 25 : 80 
Gamesix : 55 : 862
```

The txt file contains data in this format:

> {gamename} : {gamescore} : {minutesplayed}

To read the .txt I use:

```
 System.out.println("*FILE HAS BEEN LOCATED*");
    System.out.println("*File contains: \n");
    while(scan.hasNext()) 
    {
        a = scan.nextLine();
        b = scan.nextLine();
        c = scan.nextLine();
        d = scan.nextLine();
        e = scan.nextLine();
        f = scan.nextLine();
        g = scan.nextLine();
    }
```

To then split the data I use this for loop on each letter from a-to-g as shown below:

```
    //~~~~a-line-split~~~~//
    String[] aline;

    aline = a.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<aline.length; i++)
    {
        aline[i] = aline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(aline[i]);
    }
```

To clarify by validation I need to inform the user if data is missing from a line for example if line one had:

> gameone : {missing} : 1428

currently I have this simple if statement for each line:

```
            if (bline.length < 3)
            {
                System.out.println("There is an error in row one!");
            }
```

However I need to the program to know exactly where on each line the data is missing. Not just a generic response of:

```
     System.out.println("There is an error in row one!");
```

But instead something along the lines of:

```
     System.out.println("There is data missing, row: 1 column: 2");
```

Full code as requested:

```
    package readfile;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class readfile 
     {

     public static void main(String[] args)

     {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    String FileN = " ";
    String a = " ";
    String b = " ";
    String c = " ";
    String d = " ";
    String e = " ";
    String f = " ";
    String g = " ";

    boolean fileExists = false;
    File newFile = null;
    while(!fileExists) 
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you want to open: ");
      FileN = scan.nextLine();
      newFile = new File(FileN);
      fileExists = newFile.exists();
      if (!fileExists)

      {
        System.out.println(FileN + " not found...");
      }

    }
    try {
        Scanner scan2;
        scan = new Scanner(newFile);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      System.out.println("sorry but the file doesn't seem to exist");
    }


   //++++++++++++++=FILE READ=++++++++++++++++++++
    System.out.println("*FILE HAS BEEN LOCATED*");
    System.out.println("*File contains: \n");
    while(scan.hasNext()) 
    {
        a = scan.nextLine();
        b = scan.nextLine();
        c = scan.nextLine();
        d = scan.nextLine();
        e = scan.nextLine();
        f = scan.nextLine();
        g = scan.nextLine();
    }

      //+++++++++++++++ARRAYS FOR THE LINES+++++++++++++++++++

    //~~~~A-LINE~~~~//
    String[] aline;

    aline = a.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<aline.length; i++)
    {
        aline[i] = aline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(aline[i]);
    }

    //~~~~B-LINE~~~~//

    String[] bline;
    bline = b.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<bline.length; i++)
    {
        bline[i] = bline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(bline[i]);
    }

    //~~~~C-LINE~~~~//

    String[] cline;
    cline = c.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<cline.length; i++)
    {
        cline[i] = cline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(cline[i]);
    }

    //~~~~D-LINE~~~~//

    String[] dline;
    dline = d.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<dline.length; i++)
    {
        dline[i] = dline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(dline[i]);
    }

    //~~~~e-LINE~~~~//

    String[] eline;
    eline = e.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<eline.length; i++)
    {
        eline[i] = eline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(eline[i]);
    }

    //~~~~f-LINE~~~~//

    String[] fline;
    fline = f.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<fline.length; i++)
    {
        fline[i] = fline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(fline[i]);
    }

    //~~~~g-LINE~~~~//

    String[] gline;
    gline = g.split(":");

    for (int i=0; i<gline.length; i++)
    {
        gline[i] = gline[i].trim();
        //System.out.println(gline[i]);
    }

    String user       =    aline    [0];
    //~~~~~~~~~GAME NAMES~~~~~~~~~~~~~//

    //GTA
    String gameone    =    bline    [0];

    //MINECRAFT
    String gametwo  =    cline  [0];

    //ASSASSIN'S CREED IV
    String gamethree   =    dline   [0];

    //PAYDAY2
    String gamefour   =    eline    [0];

    //WOLFENSTEIN 
    String gamefive   =    fline    [0];

    //FARCRY 4
    String gamesix  =    gline  [0];




    //~~~~~~~~~~Achievement Score~~~~~~~~~~~~//


    //GTA SCORE
    String scoreone     =    bline  [1];

    //MINECRAFT SCORE
    String scoretwo     =    cline  [1];

    //ASSASSIN'S CREED IV SCORE
    String scorethree   =    dline  [1];

    //PAYDAY2 SCORE
    String scorefour    =    eline  [1];

    //WOLFENSTEIN SCORE
    String scorefive    =    fline  [1];

    //FARCRY 4 SCORE
    String scoresix     =    gline  [1];

//+++++++++++++++++++++TOTAL~~CALC++++++++++++++++++++++//
    double totalcount = 79.566; // change to the amount played.
    int totalhours = (int)totalcount;
    int totalmin = (int)(totalcount*60)%60;
    int totalsec = (int)(totalcount*(60*60))%60;
    System.out.println("TOTAL TIME PLAYED:");
    System.out.println(String.format("%s(hours) %s(minutes) %s(seconds)", 
    totalhours, totalmin, totalsec));       

     //~~~~~~~~~~Minutes Played~~~~~~~~~~~~//

    //GTA min
    String minone     =    bline    [2];

    //MINECRAFT min
    String mintwo     =    cline    [2];

    //ASSASSIN'S CREED IV min
    String minthree   =    dline    [2];

    //PAYDAY2 min
    String minfour    =    eline    [2];

    //WOLFENSTEIN min
    String minfive    =    fline    [2];

    //FARCRY 4 min
    String minsix     =    gline    [2];

    //~~~~~~~~~GAMES TEST~~~~~~~~~~~~//     

            System.out.println("\nUSER: "+user);
            System.out.println("\nDATA: ");
            System.out.println("1: "+gameone+"       | score: "+scoreone+"  
            | minutes played: "+minone);
            System.out.println("2: "+gametwo+"       | score:  "+scoretwo+" 
             | minutes played: "+mintwo);
            System.out.println("3: "+gamethree+"     | score: "+scorethree+"    
           | minutes played: "+minthree);
            System.out.println("4: "+gamefour+"          | score: 
            "+scorefour+"   | minutes played: "+minfour);
            System.out.println("5: "+gamefive+"      | score: "+scorefive+" 
           | minutes played: "+minfive);
            System.out.println("6: "+gamesix+"       | score: "+scoresix+"  
           | minutes played: "+minsix);

            if (bline.length < 3)
            {
                int column = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i<bline.length; i++){
                    column = i;
                    if(bline[i] == null || bline[i].trim() == ""){
                        System.out.println("There is an error in row two 
                  column "+(i+1));
                    }
                }
             }



}


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (bline.length < 3)
{
    int column = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<bline.length; i++){
        column = i;
        if(bline[i] == null || bline[i].trim() == ""){
            System.out.println("There is an error in row two column "+(i+1));
        }
    }
 }
```

Didn't test this but it should work

**EDIT:**

Looking at your full code `bline[2], cline[2]...` and so on will give you an Index Out of bounds exception if those values are missing from the file in the first place so before making that call you should do a check first you can create a static method to do the check

```
public static String getAtIndex(String[] array, int indexToCkeck){
    if(indexToCkeck >=array.length){
        return "";
    }
    else{
        return array[indexToCkeck];
    }
}
```

So instead of doing `bline[2], cline[2] ...` use `readfile.getAtIndex(bline, 2)` so this way if the info is missing it will return an empty string

**Also not tested, should be fine though**

Comment: This would work perfectly thank you however now when I remove data from the bline array within the .txt file I receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException how can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you should post the full code. Considering you hardcoded the number of your arrays it natural you'd get an index out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

Use a well tested library like [supercsv](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html) or [any other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209007). This will save you some hours as soon as your text format gets more complex. It also provides a good set of build-in data types to be used to validate each single column of your data. Also you can map the data directly to a POJO which can be handy in some situations.

To load just each row into a map you could do the following:

Prepare your file in stack47220687.txt:

```
Gamename: Gamescore: Minutestoplay
Gameone : 120 : 1428 
Gametwo : 20 : 10 
Gamethree : 90 : 800 
Gamefour : 190 : 2001 
Gamefive : 25 : 80 
Gamesix : 55 : 862
```

And use something like this

```
package stack47220687;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.constraint.NotNull;
import org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ift.CellProcessor;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvMapReader;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvMapReader;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

public class HowToReadACSVFile {

private static final CsvPreference COLON_DELIMITED = new CsvPreference.Builder('"', ':', "\n").build();

private static CellProcessor[] getProcessors() {
    final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { new NotNull(), // gamename
                    new NotNull(), // gamescore
                    new NotNull(), // minutestoplay
    };
    return processors;
}

@Test
public void read() throws Exception {
    ICsvMapReader mapReader = null;
    try {
        mapReader = new CsvMapReader(new FileReader(
                        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("stack47220687.txt").getPath()),
                        COLON_DELIMITED);

        // the header columns are used as the keys to the Map
        final String[] header = mapReader.getHeader(true);
        final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

        Map<String, Object> oneRecordInAMap;
        while ((oneRecordInAMap = mapReader.read(header, processors)) != null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, this line stored in a map=%s",
                            mapReader.getLineNumber(), mapReader.getRowNumber(), oneRecordInAMap));
            /**
             * oneRecordInAMap.get("Gamescore");
             */

        }

    } finally {
        if (mapReader != null) {
            mapReader.close();
        }
    }
}

}
```

works with super-csv 2.4.0

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and will print

```
lineNo=2, rowNo=2, this line stored in a map={ Gamescore= 120 , Gamename=Gameone ,  Minutestoplay= 1428 }
lineNo=3, rowNo=3, this line stored in a map={ Gamescore= 20 , Gamename=Gametwo ,  Minutestoplay= 10 }
lineNo=4, rowNo=4, this line stored in a map={ Gamescore= 90 , Gamename=Gamethree ,  Minutestoplay= 800 }
lineNo=5, rowNo=5, this line stored in a map={ Gamescore= 190 , Gamename=Gamefour ,  Minutestoplay= 2001 }
lineNo=6, rowNo=6, this line stored in a map={ Gamescore= 25 , Gamename=Gamefive ,  Minutestoplay= 80 }
lineNo=7, rowNo=7, this line stored in a map={ Gamescore= 55 , Gamename=Gamesix ,  Minutestoplay= 862}
```

It will also provide meaningful error messages if your format is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however the file types will specifically be .txt files and therefore I would be unable to use super-csv due to the  fact that after reading through their website it seems as though you cannot open txt files with that specific library.

Comment: Hi, I provide some example code that should point into the right direction.

Comment: Of course you can read txt files with it. [A CSV in fact is a plain text file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). Thanks to existing tools it is also is a very handy format if dealing with table-like structures.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to Super-CSV, i've implemented the code you suggest and it works perfectly!